# Why is a Swift Array<Int> compatible with AnyObject?

Tags: arrays, swift, object

Consider the code:

```
struct S {
    var f : Int64 = 0
}

...

let coder : NSCoder = someCoder ...
let a : [Int] = []
coder.encodeObject(a)  // compiles
let b : [Int64] = []
coder.encodeObject(b)  // doesn't compile: not AnyObject
let s : [S] = []
coder.encodeObject(s)  // doesn't compile: not AnyObject
```

Note that `Int` is defined as a `struct`.

So `[Int]` is object, but `[Int64]` is not and neither is my array of simple structures.

What is special about `Int`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you import `Foundation` (which you must be, because you reference `NSCoder`) then `[Int]` is implicitly bridged to `NSArray` because `Int` is implicitly bridged to `NSNumber`. `Int64` and your non-objc structs are not implicitly bridged to ObjC types, so arrays of those are not bridged to `NSArray`.

Comment: Just for completeness, what other kinds of types, which when used in an array, are bridged to NSArray?

Comment: Anything that conforms to `_ObjectiveCBridgeable`. Command-click on `Foundation` to get to the `Foundation` interface, then search for `_ObjectiveCBridgeable`.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-ID61 for the documentation.

Comment: @rghome Related (w.r.t. rob mayoff:s comment): you can [extend e.g. `Int64` to conform to `_ObjectiveCBridgeable`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893517/is-it-possible-to-replicate-swifts-automatic-numeric-value-bridging-to-foundatio) to allow the same implicit/automatic bridging as for `Int` in the example in your question; after which your `Int64` (elements) example will implicitly bridge to `NSNumber`, without need to explicitly perform this element-by-element `NSNumber` wrapping.

Comment: @rghome Just take care to use the extension in practice, as `_ObjectiveCBridgeable` is a Swift internal/non-public protocol that might—for any Swift update—introduce, without notice, breaking changes to any custom code of ours making direct use of (conformance to) it.

Answer (score 3):

Int is *bridged* (as are UInt and Float and Double, as well as Bool). This means that they are wrapped up in an NSNumber for you, automatically, when you cast to AnyObject, and vice versa.

Other numeric types, alas, are not.

In turn, you also get to take advantage of array-casting syntactic sugar. An NSArray must consist of Objective-C objects, such as NSNumber. When you start with a Swift array, instead of having to wrap the elements up in an NSNumber yourself, as you do with an array of Int64, they are wrapped for you when you cast/bridge a Swift array to an NSArray.

Comment: For more details on what types are bridged, see the appendix to my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_objective_c_objects_and_swift_objects

Comment: OK - thanks. You answered the comment to the other question.

Answer (score 1):

If `Foundation` framework is imported, `Int` (unlike `Int64`) is implicitly bridged to `NSNumber` which conforms to `AnyObject`